# Android toast example if edit text is empty on click event of button

Tags: android

I have two activities in my Android program & i want to pass message written in edit text of 1st active to other using click event of button, but if edit text is empty then, I want to display message using toast on click of button.

Answer (score 3):

write that piece of code in you click listener

```
if(edit_Text.getText().length()>0){

 Intent intent =new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("string",edit_Text.getText().toString());
 startActivity(intent);

 }else{

    Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this,"Edit Text Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
```

AND in yout menifest add

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity">
```

and in your secondActivity you can retrive that string value like

do that in your onCreate method of secondActivity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String string  = intent.getStringExtra("string");
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up the `OnClickListener` for your `Button`:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);

findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = editText.getText().toString()

        if (text.isEmpty()) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(CurrentActivity.this, "The edit text is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("someNameForYourText", text);
            startActivity(intent); 
        } 
    }
});
```

You can get the text back in your second activity via the following:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text = intent.getExtras().getString("someNameForYourText");
```